# Vim: Custom Shortcut for Select all and Copy

Tags: vim

I want to map a vim keyboard shortcut in **.vimrc** that copies all lines in a file to a shortcut key.  I've tried various forms of **let** and **map**, but they don't recognize the actual copy command.  I've also tried escaping the double-quotes, but that didn't work either.

What is the right way to do this?  Thanks

```
map <C-c> gg"+yG
```

Comment: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion. Also, this is for normal mode, so `:nnoremap` would be more precise. But I don't see the problem with your mapping...

Comment: Are you sure your Vim comes with clipboard support?

Comment: You're correct.  As delivered (in Ubuntu) there is not clipboard support.  But adding this enabled it:  set guioptions+=a

Comment: The usual problem with these distributions is that their standard vim is not *built* with clipboard support. To fix that, you can either install the "enhanced" vim package or you can link gvim to vim or alias gvim to "vim -v", e.g., `ln -s /usr/bin/gvim ~/bin/vim` or `alias vim='gvim -v'`.

Comment: @romainl or OP: one of you should add an answer, since you have solved this problem.